# Creating Scheduled Task using PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks, powershell-4.0, azure-powershell

I am working on script which will execute on next day and then will run every other 1,2 and 3 day(s). Here is my script:

```
#The script below will run as the specified user (you will be prompted for credentials)
#PATH C:\backup\scripts\ will need to be replaced and created in preferred location where the respective backup scripts will be stored

$jobname0 = "Full Backup"
$jobname1 = "Incremental Backup1"
$jobname2 = "Incremental Backup2"
# Change these script location to whatever you want
$script0 = "C:\backup\scripts\full.bat"
$script1 =  "C:\backup\scripts\inc1.cmd"
$script2 =  "C:\backup\scripts\inc2.ps1"
$repeat = (New-TimeSpan -Hours 72 )


# and is set to be elevated to use the highest privileges.
# The task will run every 72hrs (3days) specified in $repeat.
$action0 = New-ScheduledTaskAction –Execute "$pshome\powershell.exe" -Argument  "$script0; quit"
$action1 = New-ScheduledTaskAction –Execute "$pshome\powershell.exe" -Argument  "$script1; quit"
$action2 = New-ScheduledTaskAction –Execute "$pshome\powershell.exe" -Argument  "$script2; quit"

$duration = (New-TimeSpan -Days (365 * 20))
$trigger0 = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At 00:00AM -RepetitionInterval $repeat -RepetitionDuration $duration
$trigger1 = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At 00:01AM -RepetitionInterval $repeat -RepetitionDuration $duration
$trigger2 = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At (00:01AM).AddTime(48:00) -RepetitionInterval $repeat -RepetitionDuration $duration

$msg = "Enter the username and password that will run the task"; 
$credential = $Host.UI.PromptForCredential("Task username and password",$msg,"$env:userdomain\$env:username",$env:userdomain)
$username = $credential.UserName
$password = $credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
$settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -AllowStartIfOnBatteries -DontStopIfGoingOnBatteries -StartWhenAvailable -RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable -DontStopOnIdleEnd

Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $jobname0 -Action $action0 -Trigger $trigger0 -RunLevel Highest -User $username -Password $password -Settings $settings 
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $jobname1 -Action $action1 -Trigger $trigger1 -RunLevel Highest -User $username -Password $password -Settings $settings 
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $jobname2 -Action $action2 -Trigger $trigger2 -RunLevel Highest -User $username -Password $password -Settings $settings
```

How I can add days instead of time into the trigger. I appreciate all your help.

Comment: `(New-TimeSpan -Days 72 )` ??

Comment: You are right it should be (New-TimeSpan -Days 3). Please see additional comments below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### To answer your question precisely:

Just replace `$repeat = (New-TimeSpan -Hours 72 )` with `$repeat = (New-TimeSpan -Days 3)` and you've added days instead of <strike>time</strike> Hours.

---

### To add some additional information & tips:

Consider using [Splatting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg675931.aspx) instead of this big bunch of variables. The advantage of using variables is *reusability*. As you define e.g. `$jobname0` only to use it as parameter, it has (nearly) no advantage.

Your code could look like this

```
$credential = $Host.UI.PromptForCredential(
    "Task username and password",
    "Enter the username and password that will run the task",
    "$env:userdomain\$env:username",
    $env:userdomain
)

$repeat = (New-TimeSpan -Hours 72 )
$duration = (New-TimeSpan -Days (365 * 20))
$settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -AllowStartIfOnBatteries -DontStopIfGoingOnBatteries -StartWhenAvailable -RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable -DontStopOnIdleEnd

$job0 = @{
    "TaskName" = "Full Backup";
    "Action"   = New-ScheduledTaskAction –Execute "$pshome\powershell.exe" -Argument "C:\backup\scripts\full.bat;quit";
    "Trigger"  = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At 00:00AM -RepetitionInterval $repeat -RepetitionDuration $duration;
    "RunLevel" = "Highest";
    "User"     = $credential.UserName;
    "Password" = $credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password;
    "Settings" = $settings;
}

$job1 = @{
    "TaskName" = "2nd one";
    "Action"   = New-ScheduledTaskAction –Execute "$pshome\powershell.exe" -Argument "C:\2ndScript;quit";
    "Trigger"  = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At 10:00AM -RepetitionInterval $repeat -RepetitionDuration $duration;
    "RunLevel" = "Highest";
    "User"     = $credential.UserName;
    "Password" = $credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password;
    "Settings" = $settings;
}
#[...]
Register-ScheduledTask $job0
Register-ScheduledTask $job1
#[...]
```

Using that technique, one is able to create and reuse templates. This avoids boilerplate and duplicates.

```
$template = @{
    "TaskName" = "";
    #[...]
    "Settings" = $settings;
}

$job0 = $template.psobject.Copy()
$job1 = $template.psobject.Copy()

$job0.Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction –Execute "$pshome\powershell.exe" -Argument "MyFirstJob";
$job0.TaskName = "1stOne"
$job1.Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction –Execute "$pshome\powershell.exe" -Argument "2ndJob";
$job1.Trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At 00:00AM -RepetitionInterval $repeat -RepetitionDuration $duration;
#[...] and so on

Register-ScheduledTask @job0
Register-ScheduledTask @job1
#[...]
```

Comment: Thank you @Clijsters. I think I didn't specify my question correctly. I need to be able start task in a seuquence where first job will be executed today, next one tomorrow and third one the day after tomorrow. Thank you for pointing out the hours in $repeat it should be changed as you mentioned. I love the way you converted this script. I will use this technique as well. If I execute all task same day there is no retention policy for my backup b/c all task has been scheduled same day or with hours interval. I need to setup start date or next run with advance of one day between jobs increments.

Comment: I just converted with this configuration and I am getting message as shown below: inline `cmdlet Register-ScheduledTask at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Action[0]:` The $job0.Action has been provided and script is unable finish the execution

Comment: So you simply want to let the Trigger to be `-At` Tomorrow? As `-At` is a `[datetime]` it can just be `"01.01.2018 4:16:49 PM"` or any other known and convertible datetime-like value

Comment: @laspalmos: For your error, could you add an EDIT-section to your question providing the exact code, which produces the error? To be honest, I didn't test my snippet.

Comment: I resolved the issue instead of using **$** I used **@** for the variable inline`Register-ScheduledTask @job0` Now it works exactly how I wanted. Thank you for the hint abut the `[datetime]`

Comment: Sorry, this was a typo. @laspalmos: Please consider marking this as the answer, if it answers your question. Thanks.